# jQuery scroll scroll to bottom and making the page jumpy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple paralax effect on bootstrap carousel:

```
function paralaxCarousel() {
    var heightStart = $(".carousel .carousel-inner img").height();

    // Reset
    $(".carousel .carousel-inner").css({
        "height": heightStart,
        // 'opacity' : 1-new_opacity
    });

    $(".carousel-caption").css({
        "top": 0
    });

    $(window).unbind('scroll').scroll(function(e) {

        var scrollTopPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

        // Change the height of the carousel inner.
        $(".carousel .carousel-inner").css({
            "height": heightStart - scrollTopPosition,
            'opacity' : 1 - scrollTopPosition / 1000
        });

        // Change the position of the caption.
        $(".carousel-caption").css({
            "top": - scrollTopPosition / 2
        });
    });
}
$(window).resize(function(){
    paralaxCarousel();
});
paralaxCarousel();
```

But jquery scroll seems a bit buggy when you hold the browser scrollbar until the **bottom of the page** - it make the page **jumpy**.

Any ideas why and how I can fix this?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9f6wgjwf/1/)

You can see the page is jumpy when you **hold and scroll** the scrollbar **until** the bottom of the page.

**Notes:**
1. The bug can be seen on Chrome and Opera. Firefox seems fine.

Comment: with jquery you can add smooth animation to scroll, which will make scroll experience much better

Comment: @entre any example code?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or a snippet example? The problem stems from scrolling dominating the main thread. There are solutions, but let's see what you're actually experiencing first.

Comment: @TylerY86 i added the code to jsfiddle but it seems doesn't work there - https://jsfiddle.net/9f6wgjwf/1/

Comment: @TylerY86 but you can see the page is jumpy when you hold and scroll the scrollbar until the bottom of the page.

Comment: Works good in firefox and chrome. You may want to elaborate more what 'jumpy' is exactly. Probably add a .GIF source?

Comment: Works fine in safari also

Comment: @Manoz thanks for testing. you must hold the scrollbar and scroll way down to the bottom then you can see the bug. I tested on chrome.

Comment: @LukaKerrΔ thanks for testing. you must hold the scrollbar and scroll way down to the bottom then you can see the bug. I tested on chrome.

Comment: Might be a purely resource bound bug - redraw optimizations and threaded scrolling in Chrome and Firefox should deal with this without a hitch. Is the image that you're using for the parallax background very high resolution (like > 1024x1024, not 800x500) ?

Comment: `Is the image that you're using for the parallax background very high resolution (like > 1024x1024, not 800x500) ?` yes. but it has the bug even with a small image.